# Order of init calls in Kotlin Array initialization

Tags: arrays, kotlin, init

In the constructor of an Array is there a guarantee that the init function will be called for the indexes in an increasing order?

It would make sense but I did not find any such information in the docs:
https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-array/-init-.html#kotlin.Array%24%28kotlin.Int%2C+kotlin.Function1%28%28kotlin.Int%2C+kotlin.Array.T%29%29%29%2Finit

Comment: It is not guaranteed explicitly by the API, but there doesn't seem to be a reasonable way to implement it any other way. What problem are you trying to solve for where out of order might become an issue?

Comment: @Todd Thanks for taking the time to comment. I was thinking about putting the next N numbers read from the standard IO into an Array. Is it a conceptual mistake?

Comment: No this is not a mistake. I think you can even make this work without needing a guarantee on the execution order. Maybe ask a new question with your code, because this kind of changes the scope of the question.

Comment: @leonardkraemer: I rephrased the question with the specific code:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56192817/initializing-array-from-input-stream-in-kotlin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no guarantee for this in the API.

TLDR: If you need the sequential execution, because you have some state that changes see bottom.

First lets have a look at the implementations of the initializer:

**Native:** It is implemented in increasing order for [Kotlin Native](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/blob/bcd411837152f3546047b8703dbb493dabf0d545/runtime/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/Arrays.kt#L91).

```
@InlineConstructor
public constructor(size: Int, init: (Int) -> Char): this(size) {
    for (i in 0..size - 1) {
        this[i] = init(i)
    }
}
```

**JVM**: Decompiling the Kotlin byte code for

```
class test {
    val intArray = IntArray(100) { it * 2 }
}
```

to Java in Android Studio yields:

```
public final class test {
   @NotNull
   private final int[] intArray;

   @NotNull
   public final int[] getIntArray() {
      return this.intArray;
   }

   public test() {
      int size$iv = 100;
      int[] result$iv = new int[size$iv];
      int i$iv = 0;

      for(int var4 = result$iv.length; i$iv < var4; ++i$iv) {
         int var6 = false;
         int var11 = i$iv * 2;
         result$iv[i$iv] = var11;
      }

      this.intArray = result$iv;
   }
}
```

which supports the claim that it is initialized in ascending order.

**Conclusion:** It commonly is implemented to be executed in ascending order.

**BUT:** You can not rely on the execution order, as the implementation is not guaranteed by the API. It can change and it can be different for different platforms (although both is unlikely).

**Solution:** You can initialize the array manually in a loop, then you have control about the execution order. 
The following example outlines a possible implementation that has a stable initialisation with random values, e.g. for tests.

```
val intArray = IntArray(100).also {
    val random = Random(0)
    for (index in it.indices) {
        it[index] = index * random.nextInt()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer!

Answer (score 2):

Starting from the version 1.3.50 Kotlin has guaranteed sequential array initialization order in its API documentation: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-array/-init-.html

> The function `init` is called for each array element sequentially starting from the first one. It should return the value for an array element given its index.

Comment: No - the answer is clear - sequential array initialisation is guaranteed in 1.3.50. The link is for reference. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24199577).

Comment: I added a quoted part from the linked doc page, basically repeating what I've said in the first sentence :)