# Initialize Array of non-optionals without using constructor

Tags: arrays, kotlin, initialization, option-type

I am using an `Array` of non-optional values, and I want them to stay non-optional, but I can't use `Array`'s default constructor because of problems described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56091276).

Furthermore, the `.also{}` trick described in the linked won't work for me, because mine is not an array of some primitive type with its own special `WhateverArray` class.

Is there some Kotlin trick by which I can initialize my `a` below? Or must I resort to building some list and then converting it?

```
// please assume Stream<MyNonprimitiveType> magically gives me
// size() -> Int and
// next() -> MyNonprimitiveType
val stream : Stream<MyNonprimitiveType> = Stream<MyNonprimitiveType>()
val size : Int = stream.size()
val a : Array<MyNonprimitiveType> = ??? // use stream.next()
```

Comment: Please specify where the values are supposed to come from, so that we can unerstand precisely what the problem is, and suggest al alternative.

Comment: I will read the values from a byte stream.

Comment: So I guess you don't have any idea in advance of the number of elements this tream will contain? In that case creating a list would be the normal way to go (and lists should be preferred over arrays anyway, in general). But you don't provide many details, so we're forces to make guesses.

Comment: I do know in advance how many elements the stream will contain. I've represented that above with the `size` value.

Comment: couple of random thoughts: `var` for the array might be better than `val`, if you are doing any work at all after assigning it. Also, `ArrayList` has a lot of convenience methods that `Array` doesn't, iirc

Comment: `val a = stream.toSequence().toTypedArray()` or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a complete example doing what you want, without using a temporary list:

```
class Stream<T>(private val list: List<T>) {
    val size = list.size;
    private val it = list.iterator()

    fun next(): T {
        return it.next()
    }
}

inline fun <reified T: Any> Stream<T>.toArray(): Array<T> {
    val tmp: Array<T?> = arrayOfNulls(size)
    for (i in 0 until size) {
        tmp[i] = next()
    }
    return tmp as Array<T>
}

fun main() {
    val stream : Stream<String> = Stream(listOf("a", "b"))
    val a: Array<String> = stream.toArray()

    println(Arrays.toString(a))
}
```

Comment: Wait wait wait, I can convert `Array<T?>` to `Array<T>` using `as`?

Comment: It doesn't "convert" anything. The JVM doesn't have String[] and String?[]. Only String[]. Array<String> and Array<String?> are both mapped to String[]. So, once you guarantee that the array only contain non-null values, you can safely cast it to Array<String>.

Comment: I definitely get an unchecked conversion warning. Remember Kotlin code does not necessarily target the JVM.